# What to do if you find your question but it's unanswered?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, unanswered-questions, bump

I got a question and found [this existing question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922139/xulschool-make-no-rule-to-make-target-bin-build-needed-by-install), but it's not answered.

Since the existing question is over 2 months old, I am worried that it won't be answered.

But, my problem isn't solved, so I'm wondering if I should ask this question again, or if there is another way to "bump" the existing question to get it answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your question is essentially the same, please don't post a duplicate question.

Instead, draw attention to the existing question. Here are some ways you can do that:

- If the question has issues (misspellings, poor formatting, etc.), **edit it**. That has the side effect of bringing the question to the front page.

  You can also edit an existing question to add more information. More information may help others to solve the problem. However, if you are going to do so, be *very careful* that your edits do not change the original meaning of the question.
- [**Offer a bounty**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the question (requires reputation).
- **Share a link** to the question on social media, or email it to your contacts. The "share" link offers several convenient links, but you can share that link just about anywhere. (And, if you do that, you can earn badges when people follow your link.)

On the other hand, if your question is almost—but not quite—the same, ask a new question. Be sure to clearly explain *how* your question is different than the other (to avoid getting it closed as a duplicate), and link to the original one (to provide context).

If you have [commenting privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), you *can* post a comment on the existing question to ask the author whether they've ever found a solution. This is, technically speaking, a valid use of comments. However, we discourage you from doing so, as it generally just ends up being noise. If the author had found an answer to their question, they would have posted it. Either they haven't found an answer, or they haven't been back to the site since (in which case, they wouldn't see a comment that was left anyway).

---

More advice is here: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 4):

If you had enough rep, posting a bounty would be first of the rank, but as you say, you currently don't.

You could do some testing yourself. If that resolves it you could then post an answer to that question.  You would then probably get people commenting on your answer so you would get some feedback that way, and you might even start gaining reputation.

If the testing doesn't resolve it to your satisfaction you could then post a new question including what testing you did. That way it would be more specific than the original question and you explain that in your question and refer to the original question.

Also rather than asking "why do it this way" as the original question, ask "how to do this most efficiently" and give code examples of what you are trying to optimize.  The answer to "Why" is sometimes because "it was always done this way" dating back to a time when there was no graphic component and you had to render it yourself in an array.